# Why is adding an entry set as parameter to addall method a bad practice?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Why is the following code a bad practice and what is the solution for it?

```
TreeSet<Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, String>>> sortedtable = new TreeSet<>(new ComparatorByDueDate());


public void sortTable(Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> table){
     sortedtable.addAll(table.entrySet());
}
```

Update: As per Sonar, it is a bad practice. I am asking the question here as the sonar explanation seems confusing.

Comment: What makes you say it's a bad practice?  I can think of a couple reasons it _might_ be, depending on the use case, but it's really a question of what you're trying to do (and what that `Comparator` is doing).

Comment: A set of such mutable entries backed by the map can easily be corrupted. Furthermore Set of Entry and Map of Map is too convoluted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects are not intended for long term storage. From the docs (emphasis mine),

> A map entry (key-value pair). The `Map.entrySet` method returns a collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this collection-view. **These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration;** more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry.

If anyone, for any reason, adds, removes, or modifies any part of the map after the fact, then your `TreeSet` entries now have undefined behavior. They might still be good, they might get nulled out, they might exhibit some random behavior.

If you want to store a pair of elements, then write a class that has two instance variables. If you're on a new enough Java version, then [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) are great for this sort of thing.

Comment: So it's not safe to do this because if the underlying map changes then this also affects the entryset hence affecting the iteration of it?. The map is just meant to be read but not written to and I am using a synchronize keyword to make sure just one trhead at time is able to call the sort table method as so public synchronized void sortCardIsByDueDates Is that ok? and also is it really a bad idea to have a treeset of type Map.Entry?. I am setting it at class level.

Comment: The formal guarantee made by the implementation is: If the map is modified then all entries are invalidated. If you know for *absolutely certain* that you and everyone else viewing this code will never modify the map, then it's safe. But it's still violating the programmer's expectations, so I wouldn't let it through code review for that reason.